# Is it possible to create a asp.net mvc web application compatible with ms .net & mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I am thinking about creating my new asp.net mvc web application compatible with native ms .net as well as mono (ms server licensing cost compared to linux server licensing cost).
DB access was handled by NHibernate.

Is it possible? What are the limitations of mono regarding asp.net web applications?

Would like to hear about asp.net mvc on mono too.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have built a "sandbox" site in ASP.NET MVC compatible with MS/Mono.

Routing was my main concern and it seemed to be just fine under Mono.

I have not used NHibernate undr mono so no answer for you there unfortunately.

If you get the latest version of MonoDevelop (just ported to windows recently.) you can fire it up really quickly and see if your existing app is compatible.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

You can use NHibernate on mono, it wokrs without any problems in my experience.