# ASP.Net MVC on Linux/Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I am thinking of developing a website using the ASP.Net MVC framework on Linux. I would like to know:

- what are the best practises for developing such a site (are they any different for mono/ Windows)?
- any gotchas I should be aware of
- any (material diffeences) - e.g. missing/proprietary libraries/componenst between Mono and .Net
- are there any special directives, modules required to run Mono with Apache?
- Are there any performance differences between a site hosted on Windows/IIS and Linux/Apache?
- I intend to do most of my development using VS Studio - can the site be developed using VS and then deployed on Linux?

I am aware that this question has been asked several times here on SO. However, most of the questions  date back to 2008 or 2009 - which is a very long time in internet time. Things may have moved on since those answers - so those answers may no longer be relevant.

I have to state that I am NOT interested in hosting the site on a Windows server - so I am only interested in what works for a Linux server deployment.

Comment: The idea behind SO is that questions get updated (like on wiki), not asked again.

Comment: @skolima: So how do I ask others to update a question related to the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a asp.net mvc web application compatible with ms .net & mono?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385463/is-it-possible-to-create-a-asp-net-mvc-web-application-compatible-with-ms-net)

Comment: Vote, add comments where necessary, add proposed edits when you don't yet have the right for full edits, add a bounty if the question is important enough.

Comment: Due to history reasons, Mono web stack evolution was not as fast as its mobile front (Xamarin based), so what you read back in 2008/2009 in most cases applies still, with only a few improvements after Mono 4/5 adoption of .NET Framework source code. So you really don't need an update answer, but test your own case out please.

Answer (score 2):

I'am currently working on a MVC 4 app and we are using Mono. If you are just planning to have a basic website, you should go for it. But for more complex flows, honestly, I think you should do a little bit of research first, to see if the features you want to implement are supported in Mono. Things you should consider:

- only a set of restricted libraries are supported on mono ( for example, right now we are having some issues due to the fact that the mono libraries (Novell and DirectorySearcher) for LDAP do not support pagination)
- the developing environment will be different than your server env ( I am using Visual Studio, we managed to pass this limitation by adding a lot of logs)
- we do our publish using FTP, so yes, you can deploy it from VS, using a publish profile set up for FTP
- it's free, but it will take a lot of time to research & do special thinks just for the sake of Mono
- not a lot of documentation available, because not a lot of people use it, so if you have a specific problem, it will be more difficult to solve

Comment: How you deploy the .NET MVC 4 project on mono project? Any tutorial share with us

Answer (score 0):

My experience is from 2011, but I am pretty sure you will have to experiment to see works and what doesn't - that's my experience with Mono.

Most of your questions are extremely broad and I think your question will be soon closed.

As for your last question this was the way I did it and it worked (develop in VS->deploy to Linux), but you must be aware that:

- just because your code will work in the VS debugger it doesn't mean it will work when deployed;
- there is no one-to-one mapping between Mono and .Net. Even when things work it doesn't mean they will work the same way. For example the implementation of the encryption code used for http cookies was very different between mono and .net.